# 42a + 1001b = 7 ... How do I calculate a and b?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a pretty easy question, however, I'm struggling when I try to work it out.
I use Euclid's theorem for the first step:

1001 = 42 * (23) + 35,

42 =  35 * (1) + 7 ;  which is what is given.

Now I calculate the other way around:
7 = 42 - (1*35) = 42 - (42-7) = 7....?
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I feel like I'm missing a step.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps put commas between your equations and explain which substitutions you're doing.

Comment: Your equation is equivalent to this $6 a + 143 b=1$, $$a=24+143k;\;b=-1-6k$$

Comment: So substituting 7  by 42 - 35?.. I don't understand how I can work back to the factors 42 and 1001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Raffaele suggests, your problem is that, in order to use Euclid's algorithm, you need to have relatively prime coefficients. Here, 42a+ 1001b= 7(6a)+ 7(143b)= 7.  If the right side were not itself a multiple of 7, there would be no solution.  Since it is, divide by 7 to get 6a+ 143b= 1.

Now, 6 divides into 143 23 times with remainder 5: 5= 143- 23(6).

5 divides into 6 once with remainder 1: 1= 6- 5.

Replace "5" in that last equation by 143- 23(6): 1=
 6- (143- 23(6))= 24(6)- 143.

That is, a= 24, b= -1 is a solution to 6a+ 143b= 1.  Of course, it is easy to see that a= 24- 143k, b= -1+ 6k is also a solution for any integer k.

Answer (score 0):

Since $6a =-143b+1$ we have $$6\mid (-143b+1)+144b=b+1$$ So $b=6k-1$ and $a=-143k+24$ for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Working forwards only:

$\begin{align}
(1)\times 1001 & & &=1001\\
 & & (1)\times 42 &=42\\
(1)\times 1001 & \qquad + & (-23)\times 42 &=35\\
(-1)\times 1001 & \qquad + & (24)\times 42 &=7\\
(6)\times 1001 & \qquad + & (-143)\times 42 &=0\\
\end{align}$

each time just subtracting a multiple of the previous equation line from the one above to get the smallest non-negative result. This gives a base case for your equation on the "$=7$" line and the multipliers to get other results on the "$=0$" final line.

$(-1+6k)\times 1001 + (24-143k)\times 42 = 7$

The problem with your backwards working was simply that you didn't substitute 
$35 = (1\times 1001 - 23\times 42)$ into $7=42-35$, which gives the same result as above, $7=42 - (1\times 1001 - 23\times 42) = -1\times 1001 + 24\times 42$.